# Move files into existing folders containing part of the filename

Tags: powershell, file, batch-file, directory, move

You would think that this is a duplicate post, but I have been on this for 2 days now. I have tried filebot, filejuggler, robobasket, moveout and advanced renamer. I have searched all over the web, and nothing fixes my problem.

I have a file named `12345678.txt`, and want to move it into the directory `C:\folders\12345678-bla bla bla\`

Everything I tried moved the file into a folder it created with the exact same name as the file. However my folder has other caracters after the name of the file.

Here is the exact real situation:

In this directory: `C:\F\Répertoires\FISCALITE\T2\2020` I have files named with the client number e.g. `75063420.txt`. I need to move that file into this folder: `C:\F\Répertoires\CLIENTS\750634_Entreprises nameofcompany\`

So only the first `6` characters of the filename are needed to match the existing folder where the name has more characters than the filename.

I have maybe 5000 files to move and need an automated way of doing it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show what you tried so far (i.e. your code) and where it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a powershell way to do this without any error or conflict handling like multiple client directories with the same six starting characters or files that exist already in the client folder.

```
$FilesToMove = 'C:\F\Répertoires\FISCALITE\T2\2020'
$TargetPath = 'C:\F\Répertoires\CLIENTS'

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $FilesToMove -File

foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $PathToMove = Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetPath -Directory -Filter "$(($File.Basename).Substring(0,6))*" | Select-Object -First 1
    Write-Output "Moving File $File to $PathToMove"
    Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination "$($PathToMove.Fullname)\$($File.Name)"
}
```

Comment: OMG Olaf, youre the best! I have spent days on this and had tried similar PS scripts but this works exactly as it should. I really really appreshiate your help. I can now spend time with my familly this weekend! Have a great day. :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@Set "SourcePath=C:\F\Répertoires\FISCALITE\T2\2020"
@Set "TargetPath=C:\F\Répertoires\CLIENTS"
@Set "FileMask=??????*.*"
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
    '""%__AppDir__%where.exe" "%SourcePath%":"%FileMask%" 2>NUL"'
)Do @Set "BaseName=%%~nA"&For /F "Delims=" %%B In (
    'Dir /B/AD "%TargetPath%\%%BaseName:~,6%%_*" 2^>NUL'
)Do @Move /Y "%%A" "%TargetPath%\%%~nxB">NUL 2>&1
```

On line `3`, I have used the wildcard `*` to match all extensions, `??????*.*`. If you're only looking for a particular extension, lets say `.txt` as in your example, you could use `??????*.txt`, which will match all `.txt` files containing six or more characters in their basename. If you modify the source and/or target path, please ensure that it doesn't have a trailing path separator, `\`.

*If it is possible to have more than one directory in the `%TargetPath%` with the same `6` character prefix, I'd suggest you either accept that it will be moved to the first returned, or change the `move` command to `copy`, then perform a `delete` afterwards.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for `filebot`:

```
filebot -rename "C:\F\Répertoires\FISCALITE\T2\2020" --db file --output "C:\F\Répertoires\CLIENTS" --format "{output.list().find{ it.startsWith(fn) } / fn}"
```

You'll want to add `--action TEST` or `--action COPY` when testing and prototyping the command.