# Move files to a folder if filename contains folder name

Tags: move

I am trying to move files of various extensions to a folder if the filename contains the folder name.

Simple example: I have several files such as Fox-1.doc, Fox-2.doc, etc. I have a folder named Fox. I'm trying to move the files into the folder Fox if folder name is contained in the filename.

I tried to modify the code in the following post but I was not successful.

[Move files into existing folders containing part of the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58357820/move-files-into-existing-folders-containing-part-of-the-filename/58359380#58359380)

Any pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code for doing this try getting the filename and filter from the .contains() method often found in Strings.

If you are using Linux command line I think this could work

```
mv *fox* destination_path/
```

For Powershell I found this thread that could help you:
[powershell to move files based on part of file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117208/powershell-to-move-files-based-on-part-of-file-name)

All you'd have to do is create the .ps1 with the modified script.

Comment: I believe I can use that Powershell code. I am a little new to scripting and not sure how to use .contains() in this case. I have a list of subfolders already created in the same folder as the files. How would I use .contains() to find the folder name that is contained in the filename, then move the file into that folder?

Answer (score 0):

For those who still concern and without access to chatgpt

```
FOR /D %I IN ("A\*") DO (
  MOVE "A\*%~nI*" "%I"
)
```

The FOR loop iterates over all the subfolders in folder A, which are represented by the wildcard pattern `A*`.

- The `/D` option tells FOR to only iterate over directories (i.e., subfolders).
- The `%I` variable is used to represent each subfolder name in turn.

The MOVE command moves any files in folder A that have a name containing the subfolder name (`%~nI`) to the corresponding subfolder (`%I`). The asterisk (*) is used as a wildcard to match any characters before or after the subfolder name.